# make same actions for all elements inside ul li

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-lists

I have an unordered list in which every list item has a span and inside of it a picture.
I'm trying to set as background-image of every span, the image that their inner img block contains and then put the opacity of that image block to 0.

Here's the code I wrote. The problem is that this seems not work correctly, even if I coomment the line where I set the background image, I still can see the pictures, while I wouldn't be supposed of, since the opacity of the img block is set to 0. That makes me think that the code isn't setting the background image correctly.

Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong?
thank you!

```js
var myUl = $('.my-ul');
  
    [...myUl.children].forEach(childLi => {
        const span_list = childLi.querySelector('span');
        const img_list = childLi.querySelector('img');
        var path_picture = img_list.src;
        $(span_list).css("background-image", "url(${path_picture})");
        $(span_list).css("background-size", "contain");
        img_list.style.opacity = 0;
  });
```

```css
 .my-ul li span {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }

  .my-ul li img {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="my-ul">
  <li>
    <span>
      <img src="https://www.trudellanimalhealth.com/sites/default/files/documents/tmdi-cat-athma-concern_2x.png" />
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
      <img src="https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg" />
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
      <img src="https://undark.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/GettyImages-1199242002-1-scaled.jpg" />
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: myUl.children is not iterable` - please fix all obvious code errors

Comment: Change `"url(${path_picture})"` to `\`url(${path_picture})\`` and fix the children iteration and it works fine

Comment: I was working on that but I don't understand why my ul variable is not iterable

Comment: `myUl` is a jquery collection, it has a `.children()` function, but it's not an array - looks like you're mixing jquery and vanilla

Comment: so the problem is that I'm using "forEach" ? I'm quite new to this so I bult my code out piece of documentation I found online

Comment: No, it's not that you're using `.forEach` - it's that your trying to use an array function on a jquery collection.  If you stick with vanilla js `document.querySelector(".my-ul")` then the arrary function `[...collection]` will do as you're expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues:

- `$(".myul")` returns a jquery collection, which as a `.children()` function (not a property) but this is not an array, so can't be iterated using `[...].forEach`
- `"url(${path_picture})"` looks like it uses string interpolation, so needs to use backtick ` not quote `"`

Giving:

```js
//var myUl = $('.my-ul');
var myUl = document.querySelector(".my-ul");

[...myUl.children].forEach(childLi => {
  const span_list = childLi.querySelector('span');
  const img_list = childLi.querySelector('img');
  var path_picture = img_list.src;
  $(span_list).css("background-image", `url(${path_picture})`);
  $(span_list).css("background-size", "contain");
  img_list.style.opacity = 0;
});
```

```css
.my-ul li span {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.my-ul li img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="my-ul">
  <li>
    <span>
      <img src="https://www.trudellanimalhealth.com/sites/default/files/documents/tmdi-cat-athma-concern_2x.png" />
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
      <img src="https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg" />
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
      <img src="https://undark.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/GettyImages-1199242002-1-scaled.jpg" />
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The alternative is to use jquery

```js
var myUl = $('.my-ul');

myUl.children().each((i, e) => {
  var path_picture = $("img", e).attr("src");
  $("span", e)
      .css("background-image", `url(${path_picture})`)
      .css("background-size", "contain");
  $("img", e).hide();
});
```

```css
.my-ul li span {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.my-ul li img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="my-ul">
  <li>
    <span>
      <img src="https://www.trudellanimalhealth.com/sites/default/files/documents/tmdi-cat-athma-concern_2x.png" />
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
      <img src="https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg" />
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
      <img src="https://undark.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/GettyImages-1199242002-1-scaled.jpg" />
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I didn't notice that I mixed vanilla and jquery. What I want to stick to jquery, how can I iterate the process for every list item without using an array object? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you handle changing styles in vanilla js or jquery, but it could be this `img_list.style.opacity = 0;` is wrong. Maybe `img_list` is a group of elements/nodes so it won't work?